# Windows is not booting any more after resizing "/"

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

On my machine I have two ubuntu partitions and one windows partition. Everything was fine, until I had to increase the size of the / partition of one of the ubuntu installs. I basically moved the / from /dev/sda8 to /dev/sda10 (there's a guide on ubuntu wiki about how to do that).

Everything went fine, except that I lost the ability of booting on windows. There's still the windows entry in grub, but whenever I click on it, I'm sent back to the grub window. Any help?

Here's the output of "bootinfoscript" (unfortunately, I'm not understanding it that much) -> http://pastebin.com/WNwvsXn5

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: You might try to repair the windows bootloader via the windows repair DVD and after that recreate GRUB via chrooting into your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: I don't have the windows DVD, is it possible to do that from the recovery partition?

Comment: You can get windows repair cds in the internet and you can even download Windows 7 Installation CDs from Microsoft (Just google for Windows ISOs, for 7 they are provided from Microsoft as 60 day trials [Profressional and Home Premium, but that doesn't matter, because you can use anyone for recovery purposes]).

Answer (score 2):

Do `sudo update-grub` and, if it don't work, edit grub.cfg manually with `sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg` from a terminal. This last option **requires** some knowledge.
 I suggest you to read [this basic guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) before doing any change.
**Always** remember to use update-grub after each change, it's very important.
Have a nice day.

Edit in response to the comment: you should find the "BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober" string in the file. There should be the Windows entry.
Verify that the data there is right:
(it should be like this, except for the last line)

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows NT/2000/XP (su /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-C2F0E263F0E25D63' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd0,msdos2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  C2F0E263F0E25D63
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C2F0E263F0E25D63
        fi
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

No, your data doesn't seems right (from the pastebin):

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-909C7C3E9C7C20C0' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd0,msdos2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  909C7C3E9C7C20C0
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 909C7C3E9C7C20C0
        fi
        chainloader +1
}
```

...because Windows should be on sda3 and not on sda2! (see sda3 on bootifoscript.txt)
Try to use [this specific software](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10871917#post10871917) to fix your problem, it should be a better alternative to manual grub.cfg editing in this specific case.
If you still don't solve feel free to write it.

Comment: I `sudo update-grub`ed from any of the three partitions that I have, but this didn't change. I think to be enough good with playing around with grub and similar things, otherwise I wouldn't be able to move a the root partition easily (actually, that wasn't that easy since I had to change some commands w.r.t. the guide).
My question is: what I should do in the `grub.cfg` file?

Comment: Answered with an edit. After you've made any change you can rename the grub entry and delete the "(loader)" string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it still possible to simply modify the grub.cfg to change the `set root='hd0,msdos2'` into `set root='hd0,msdos3'`, am I right? That should fix the issue, or not?

Comment: My problem is that I've always had Windows on /dev/sda2, so probably when I moved the root partition something was messing up and a new /dev/sda2 has been created. Is it possible?

Comment: Do a cfg backup and try, only avoid to edit other entries in the cfg file; be sure to change any reference to the old partition and to run the update command I cited up. A DESPERATE CASE: you can always delete the Windows partition, create a one big partition and install there Windows another time. You can do this from Ubuntu or from a Live distro. Remember to backup your documents from Windows on the linux partition (from linux, it can see the Windows partition) or, more safely, by doing a traditional backup.