# What to do when Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit does not boot?

Tags: boot, 13.10

Ubuntu 13.10 will not boot, it won't even show the grub menu or Ubuntu booting. There is just a purple screen for 20 seconds then a black screen, then the screen says entering power save mode. here are my system specs:Intel DQ965GF Motherboard (OS independant), Intel core 2 64-bit, 12GB HHD (SATA), 200GB HHD (SATA, installed here), 250GB HHD (SATA, Encrypted with LUKS), 3GB DDR2 RAM (DIMM 0 A 1024MB,DIMM 1 A 524MB, DIMM 0 B 1024MB, DIMM 1 B 524MB),2 Rewritable DVD drives (one SATA and one IDE), small floppy drive and car reader, and AMD gallium 0.4. That's all I know from the top of my head, I have no OS to give me more info on the graphics card, but all Ubuntu OSs worked on my PC from 12.04-13.04 just fine. Does this mean  will never be able to use Ubuntu 13.10? I think I am screwed.

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose that your hardware is OK (the power save mode is handled by your screen).
Maybe your GRUB configuration file has been truncated/corrupted; I suggest to directly reinstall Ubuntu from a new media. Follow carefully this procedure:

- Download the last version **from torrent**; **if** you can't use HTTP (standard download) but after that **check the MD5 sum of the file** (torrent clients will do a similar operation automatically).
- Buy a new DVD and check it's integrity.
- From your BIOS option (try F2, F8, CANC ecc. more times at the power on) disable any builtin boot sector protection (like the boot VIRUS protection) and any Interl/AMD fast -startup option (like the "SpeedStep").
- Burn and Install Ubuntu **without** the internet connection support.
- Remove the DVD and let it cool down; close the reader/writer device.
- Close the reader/writer device and reboot.
- Press ENTER on the Ubuntu entry of the GRUB menu. Don't press other keys.

**If this procedure doesn't function** you can burn a Live Distribution to check your GRUB configuration or use a specific software. I've already talked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356824/windows-is-not-booting-any-more-after-resizing/356840#356840) about this type of problems with GRUB; the specific software (in the bottom of the post) can be also installed on a Live Distro.
A suggestion: don't throw away your old Linux DVDs, they can always be useful, so conserve them in a safe & dark place.
Let me know with a comment if you solve or not, I'll answer to your questions.